# How to select all relations that current user is involved in ? ASP.NET SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, t-sql

I have this database with users and relations. I simply want to show `username`, `firstName` and `lastName` of all the relations that some specific (current logged in user) `userID` is present in. How do I do this?

This is my best try.

```
SELECT 
    UserRelationship.relationshipType, 
    UserRelationship.userFirstID, UserRelationship.userSecondID, 
    [User].username, [User].firstName, [User].lastName
FROM  
    [User] 
INNER JOIN
    UserRelationship ON [User].userID = UserRelationship.userFirstID 
                     AND UserRelationship.relationshipType = 'friends' 
                     OR [User].userID = UserRelationship.userSecondID 
                     AND UserRelationship.relationshipType = 'friends'
WHERE 
    ([User].userID = @userID)
```

This returns all relations, but the username, firstname and lastname of current user.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRelationship] 
(
    [userFirstID]      INT           NOT NULL,
    [userSecondID]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [initiatedBy]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [relationshipType] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserRelationship] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userFirstID] ASC, [userSecondID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRelationship_userFirstID] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([userFirstID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([userID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserRelationship_initiatedBy] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([initiatedBy]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([username]),
    CONSTRAINT [CK_UserRelationship_relationshipType] 
        CHECK ([relationshipType]='pending' OR [relationshipType]='friends')
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] 
(
    [userID]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [username]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [firstName]   NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [lastName]    NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [dateOfBirth] DATE           NULL,
    [city]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [address]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [phoneNumber] INT            NULL,
    [email]       NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [rank]        NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [profilImage] NVARCHAR (255) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_User_username] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([username] ASC)
);
```

In my `UserRelationship` table, I store all relations by always making sure `userFirstID` is lower than `userSecondID`. So I only have 1 record per relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the names of the users the current user has a friendship with? Then one possibility is to join the user's table again twice for each the first and the second id in the relationship's table and check in a `CASE ... END` which one is the other user and return their name.

```
SELECT UserRelationship.relationshipType,
       UserRelationship.userFirstID,
       UserRelationship.userSecondID,
       [User].username,
       [User].firstName,
       [User].lastName,
       CASE [User].[UserID]
         WHEN OtherUser1.userId
           THEN OtherUser2.userName
         WHEN OtherUser2.userId
           THEN OtherUser1.userName
       END OtherUserUserName,
       CASE [User].[UserID]
         WHEN OtherUser1.userId
           THEN OtherUser2.firstName
         WHEN OtherUser2.userId
           THEN OtherUser1.firstName
       END OtherUserFirstName,
       CASE [User].[UserID]
         WHEN OtherUser1.userId
           THEN OtherUser2.lastName
         WHEN OtherUser2.userId
           THEN OtherUser1.lastName
       END OtherUserLastName
       FROM [User]
            INNER JOIN UserRelationship
                       ON [User].userID IN (UserRelationship.userFirstID,
                                            UserRelationship.userSecondID)
                          AND UserRelationship.relationshipType = 'friends' 
            INNER JOIN [User] OtherUser1
                       ON OtherUser1.userID = UserRelationship.userFirstID
            INNER JOIN [User] OtherUser2
                       ON OtherUser2.userID = UserRelationship.userSecondID
       WHERE ([User].userID = @userID);
```

(Assuming a user cannot be a friend of themselves. That would require an extension of the `CASE .... END`s for the case of all three ids being equal.)